# Fully Persistent B+ Tree

Tags: c, b-plus-tree

I'm trying to implement B+ tree (in C language) with each ***key*** being some data(int/float/string) and corresponding ***value*** is a list, whose size is not fixed.

I want to store this tree in a file and access later on, when required. You may consider the implementation as follows:

- Each search key corresponds to a page in the file and
- Each page contains set of values corresponding to that key

The problem is: I cannot just assign a page to a key, as it may consume very little and waste the entire page. So I need a persistent way of implementing B+ tree in file system, instead of main-memory.

Comment: There is no tag for B+Tree, so added B-Tree tag. But it is for B+Tree

Comment: Have you considered simply using the SQLite database for this?  That will allow you to store a database of key/value pairs on disk.

Comment: What sort of performance do you need for this?  Could you just serialize your data in JSON?  You mention a "page"... what do you have in mind for a "page"?

Comment: chaithanya, Note B+ Trees are distinct from B-Trees.

Comment: He was right, there wasn't a tag for B+ trees.  I edited to add the "b-plus-tree" tag since the string "b+tree" wasn't permitted.

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 I do understand that they are different. So commented above.

Comment: @steveha Page is a some contiguous amount of memory in a file, so that I can consider a file to be as set of pages, each page being referenced by a key

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag. I have no sufficient score to create a new tag. I cannot use JSON or SQLite, as this code is part of a huge code written in C.

Comment: I don't see a specific question. I don't see a description of what you tried to make it persistent, and why it didn't work.

Comment: My question is to find a strategy that will allow me to store the values of a key contiguously and to be able to retrive them later on. You can think of this problem as implementing B+tree on files

Comment: @chaithanya Please note that the tag `b+-tree` is currently a synonym of `b-tree`.  While they may be separate concepts, people in the past disagreed enough to make them synonyms.  If you feel passionately that they're totally different things, you might want to head over to Meta and ask that the synonym be broken.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [disk-based B-tree implementation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/WB) out, it might be help.

And this paper titled *[Fully Persistent B+-Trees](http://library.riphah.edu.pk/acm/disk_1/text/1-2/SIGMOD91/P426.PDF)*

Comment: Please avoid link only answer as answer becomes obsolete as link changes or fails.

Comment: Paper might be useful, but I don't even remember whether I solved the problem. Anyway thanks for post. Upvoting the answer but not accepting, as I'm not sure of it.

Comment: The pdf link is dead, as it was guessed 2 years back.